# How would I prevent logging in with the same username at the localhost server?

Tags: php, html, mysql

How would I prevent a user from logging into their account on the localhost server, including all browsers in the pc (together with incognito mode)?
Here is what I've tried:

```
if($_SESSION['username']==$ausername)
```

But it only works on one browser, it doesn't work on the incognito mode of that browser including other browsers. 
Thanks guys!

ADD: I've already tried creating a field in my table that will contain the status of the account (YES/NO), but I'm having a problem in the case that they accidentally close their browser, the user will not able to use their account again, unless that field has been changed to "NO"

Comment: Well yeah. Session aren't shared between browsers, or between public / private sessions. Do you have an actual use case for this that isn't pointless? You'd have to keep a list of logged in users somewhere and check it every time somebody tries to log in. And some how keep it up-to-date, which gets a bit awkward if somebody for example closes their browser without explicitly logging out.

Comment: Session save per browser. you can save in DB and check if user exits.

Comment: @JonStirling So what's the quick fix for this to prevent a user to log in his account with multiple browsers at the server?

Comment: @Avihaym already tried that but what if the browser accidentally closed? he/she will not use his/her account again.

Comment: Try to use js or jquery events when tab or browser closed

Comment: @Avihaym yes already tried adding

<sessionState mode="InProc"></sessionState>

to kill the session if the browser is closed. but my problem is in the server.

Comment: @maxnamd My suggestion is, don't bother. Let them log in where ever they like. If they log in in multiple places, so what?

Comment: $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
    // remove session
})